# How to avoid jquery converting hex color values to rgb with $('#selector').html()

Tags: jquery, hex, rgb

I use TinyMCE (jquery variant) as an editor. When the user clicks a button, i read out the text he entered with

```
editorValue = $('#tinyMceEditor').val();
```

If the user has styled the text with color for example the return could be something like

```
"<p><span style="color: #888888;">hello</span></p>"
```

This is then placed in a <td>.

```
$('#myTd').html(editorValue);
```

Now when i read out the td with

```
$('#myTd').html();
```

Internet Explorer and Firefox return me

```
"<p><span style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136);">hello</span></p>"
```

While Chrome returns me

```
"<p><span style="color: #888888;">hallo</span></p>"
```

I did a bit of research and read that Jquery uses rgb values because it calculates animations and such this way. But this way the .html() selector isn't returning the real content of the node.

Is there an easy way to avoid this conversion and have it everywhere as with chrome.
It is necessary for my application because it compares strings that need to match.

Comment: I don't think jQuery is doing the conversion with `.html()`. You can confirm this by replacing `$("#myTd").html()` with `$("#myTd")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: The fact that different browsers give different results implies that it is not jquery but the browser that is causing this.

Comment: @KevinB Well in the example below in IE9 (Standards mode, not quirks mode) the alert message i see has changed the color property.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    alert($('#myTd').html());
});
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myTd">
            <p><span style="color: #666666;">Hello world</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Comment: @JamesMontagne It might be browser specific but when calling jquery methods mainly to get the value or html and set it elsewhere IE and FF convert the color property. If I do a .val() on the tinymce textarea in the console i get color in the hex format. Once it's placed in the td FF converts this to rgb (looking through firebug).

My main issue is to get the same result in every browser so the strings match

Comment: @JamesMontagne You're right. doing `document.getElementById()` produces the same result at least in IE (hex gets converted to rgb). Which means I'll need to take another approach.